# Displaying token to user

Tags: swift, rest, jwt, access-token

I have an auth system using JWT in my iOS app. I receive an access token from the server and use it for each request. Can I show that token to the user? Why it might be unsafe?

Comment: What is the benefit for the user?

Comment: Adding to @vadian, who the user is? Is it the app that needs to know about token? Then it's ok. If it is an app user  then no. You should not expose your tokens to end users. And user will not care about token. It is sensitive and NOT encrypted(just encoded) it may leak sensitive data

Comment: An _access token_ implemented as JWT would be opaque to the application. There's no reason for the app nor the user to know the internal details of an access token. An app receives it from the authorization endpoint and includes it in an user resource endpoint. Also, an access token is a _secret_ - it must not be exposed to the outside of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is safe to show the JWT to the user depends on the information in it and your organization's policy wrt. that information. If there's only information about the user in the token, it is OK in most cases. But if there's information that you want to hide from the user - which may also include information about that user that is intended for other recipients only - then no.

Basically the token is available to the user anyhow, since it is in an app on his device. He could get to it by intercepting the communication (endpoint) or inspecting the memory contents.

So if there is information you really need to hide from the user, the token issuer should encrypt the JWT.

Comment: The OP asked specifically for exposing an _access token_. Access tokens are secrets and must be kept enclosed securely in the application. Exposing them via an UI, would make it possible that anyone else may capture it and then compose and recreate them for malicious use. Thus, showing them to a "user" is a strong NO - and there is no exception. Even accidentally writing them in a log file or in analytics is a security flaw.

Comment: you assume a lot of things that are not part of my answer, I would advise you to read it again with more attention and it will make you see the difference; also, your bottom line about never making access tokens available to an end user is simply false

Comment: The complete JWT (including the signature) constitutes a credential. There is little to no reason to show the claims (user id, scope, issuer, expiration date, etc.) from an access token to an end user. Even the client does not need to decode the JWT and treats it as an opaque sequence of bytes.

Comment: the credential was actually issued on behalf of the user; there's is little to no reason to look at it for sure, but it is safe, which was what the question was about;